# html node parsing with ASP classic

Tags: parsing, html, asp-classic

I stucked a day's trying to find a answer: is there a possibility with classic ASP, using MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0 - to parse html code and extract a content of a HTML node by gived ID? For example:

**remote html file:**

```
<html>
.....
<div id="description">
some important notes here
</div>
.....
</html>
```

**asp code**

```
<%    
    ...
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    objHTTP.Open "GET", url_of_remote_html, False
    objHTTP.Send
    ...
%>
```

Now - i read a lot of docs, that there is a possibility to access HTML as source (objHTTP.responseText) and as structure (objHTTP.responseXML). But how in a world i can use that XML response to access content of that div? I read and try so many examples, but can not find anything clear that I can solve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First up, perform the GET request as in your original code snippet:

```
Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
http.Open "GET", url_of_remote_html, False
http.Send
```

Next, create a regular expression object and set the pattern to match the inner html of an element with the desired id:

```
Set regEx = New RegExp
regEx.Pattern = "<div id=""description"">(.*?)</div>"
regEx.Global = True
```

Lastly, pull out the content from the first submatch within the first match:

```
On Error Resume Next
contents = regEx.Execute(http.responseText)(0).Submatches(0)
On Error Goto 0
```

If anything goes wrong and for example the matching element isn't found in the document, `contents` will be `Null`. If all went to plan `contents` should hold the data you're looking for.

Comment: well, regex - of course :) thank you! This work fine for unique tags (which is my case). Polynomial - thank you again

Comment: No worries. If you wanted to grab data from a less specific tag, or to grab data from multiple tags in the document, you could write different patterns and loop through the matches that `Execute()` returns - there is a lot of scope.