# direct image link from http://postimage.org/

Tags: html, asp-classic, image-uploading, bbcode, imagedownload

I am using asp/html code. For some time now I am trying to retrieve a *direct image link* from http://postimage.org/ to my database.

I usually retrieve info from pages by form or sessions. Have done some Google research but found no useful info.
Found the field where the direct-image-link is shown but how do I extract it?

```
<tr>
    <td><textarea wrap='off' onmouseover='this.focus()' onfocus='this.select()' id="code_2" scrolling="no">http://s24.postimg.org/xcbpadh6d/NO_PICTURE.jpg</textarea></td>
    <td style="width:170px;"><span id="result_2">Direct Link</span></td>
    <td><div id="clip_button_2" class="my_clip_button" data-clipboard-target="code_2">copy to clipboard</div></td>
</tr>
```

The task is to retrieve the direct link **without** go threw the upload image of the site and copying the link.  (never done this before so don't know how to do it but I do understand it need's server side script) .

The site offers bbc code for this purpose:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mod.postimage.org/website-english.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

but I have no idea how to integrate it in my asp/html code. There are sites like http://www.bbcode-to-html.com/ that provides conversion tools from bbc to html but they didn't help.

```
<p><script type="text/javascript" src="http://mod.postimage.org/website-english.js" charset="utf-8"></script></p>
```

Comment: The code you quote is HTML, not BBCode.

Comment: Really need more information - you really haven't given us enough to go on

Comment: if i only knew myself what to provide but this is a completely new theme for me in asp/html field

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question, you can parse html page (where your first code snippet is from) in asp code. See [html node parsing with ASP classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20311626/html-node-parsing-with-asp-classic)

PS. Sorry for my english, I'm from Finland (Santa lives here!)

Comment: hahah you killed me lol thanks for the smile ....santa lives here :))) so basically what you offer is to download the whole page and then extract ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I would do.

Comment: That's overkill - explain it the simplest terms you can what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

I tried to parse images of this site by generating a token of images. The possible number of tokens is 13537086546263552. It takes ~ 25 years to check all keys with an average rate of one token per second)

Try this:

```
//$html - postimg curl response

preg_match_all('/property="og:image"[\s]content="\D.*"/', $html, $matches);
$img = preg_split('/[\"]/', $matches[0][0]);
echo $img[3];
```